# Painless Scripting Kibana 6.4.2 not matching using matcher, but matches using expression conditional

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

Hello I'm trying to take a substring of a log message using regex in kibana scripted fields. I've run into an interesting scenario that doesn't add up. I converted the message field to a keyword so I could do scripted field operations on it.

When I match with a conditional such as:

```
if (doc['message'].value =~ /(\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b)/) { 
return "match"
} else {
return "no match"
}
```

This will match the ip and return correctly that there is an ip in the message. However, whenever I try to do the matcher function which splits the matched text into substrings it doesn't find any matches.

Following the guide on Elastic's documentation for doing this located here:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-painless-kibana-scripted-fields

This is the example script they give to match the first octet of an ip in a log message. However, this returns no matches when indeed there is ip addresses in the log message. I can't even match just text characters no matter what I do it returns 0 matches.

I have enabled rexex in the elasticsearch.yml in my cluster as well.

```
def m = /^([0-9]+)\..*$/.matcher(doc['message'].value);
if ( m.matches() ) {
   return Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))
} else {
   return m.matches() + " - " + doc['message'].value;
}
```

This returns 0 matches. Even if I use the same expression used for the conditional:

/(\b(?:\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}\b)/

the matcher will still return false.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here according to the documentation this should work.

I tried using subs-strings when the value exists in the if conditional but there is to many variations between the log messages. I also don't see a way to split and look through the list of outputs to pick the one with ip if I just use conditional for the scripted field.

Any idea on how to solve this:

Here is a example of that is returned form

```
def m = /^([0-9]+)\..*$/.matcher(doc['message'].value);
if ( m.matches() ) {
   return Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))
} else {
   return m.matches() + " - " + doc['message'].value;
}
```

The funny part is they all return false and this is essentially just looking for numbers with . and I've tried all kinds of regex combinations with no luck.

```
[
 {
  "_id": "VRYK_2kB0_nHZ_3qyRwt",
  "Source-IP": [
   "false - #Version: 1.0"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "VhYK_2kB0_nHZ_3qyRwt",
  "Source-IP": [
   "false - 2019-02-17 00:34:11 127.0.0.1 GET /status/web - 8611 - 127.0.0.1 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 31"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "VxYK_2kB0_nHZ_3qyRwt",
  "Source-IP": [
   "false - #Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "WBYK_2kB0_nHZ_3qyRwt",
  "Source-IP": [
   "false - #Date: 2019-03-26 00:00:08"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "WRYK_2kB0_nHZ_3qyRwt",
  "Source-IP": [
127.0.0.1 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 15"
  ]
 },
 {
```

Answer (score 2):

ended up being the following:

```
if (doc["message"].value != null) { 
  def m = /(\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b)/.matcher(doc["message"].value); 
  if (m.find()) { return m.group(1) } 
  else { return "no match" } 
} 
else { return "NULL"}
```

Comment: well it matches in the results when I run it in the test window, but the actual ip field is only the first two octets.

Comment: setting string type fiexed it and it works. this strips the ip out.